# how can i get text on web without any tag using bs4?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

this is data structure

```
<div class = 'xxx' id = 'yyy'>
     <div class id = 'zzz' class = 'kkk'>
<script type = 'bbb'>
// noise word
</script>
<strong class = '111'>...</strong>
<span class = '222'>...</span>

<br>
### target data
<br>
### target data2
<br>
### target data 3

<a href="http://news.khan.co.kr/kh_cartoon/?utm_source=naver&amp;utm_medium=news_bottom_outlink" target="_blank">▶ 장도리 | 그림마당 보기</a><br/><a href="http://www.khan.co.kr/?utm_source=naver&amp;utm_medium=news_bottom_outlink" target="_blank">▶ 경향신문 바로가기</a><a href="http://smile.khan.co.kr/gudoc/gudoc_input_step3.html?media_cd=201&amp;utm_source=naver&amp;utm_medium=news_bottom_outlink" target="_blank">▶ 경향신문 구독신청하기</a><br/><br/>©경향신문(www.khan.co.kr), 무단전재 및 재배포 금지<br/><br/>
<!-- // 본문 내용 -->
</div>

... etc
```

i wanna get only target data. and i use bs4 for get word data in html.

bellow is my source code to get word

```
soup.find_all('div',{'id':'yyy'})
```

but it's return to many noise data.

#### how can i get only target data use bs4 with selenium??

---

[this is target url and i wanna get text in article body](https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LS2D&mid=shm&sid1=100&sid2=264&oid=016&aid=0001737526)

and bellow is my parsing source code

```
    def crwaling_article(self,url):
        """
        

        Parameters
        ----------
        url : List
            Article URL to get data.

        Returns : DataFrame
            Article Description Data Frame 
        -------
        None.

        """
        chrome_driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/바탕 화면/인턴/python/crawling_software/crwaler/news_crwaling/chromedriver.exe')
        chrome_driver.get(url)
        html = chrome_driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html , 'html.parser')
        
        title = soup.find('div',{'class':'article_info'}).find('h3',{'id':'articleTitle'}).get_text()
        date = soup.find('div', {'class':'article_info'}).find('span',{'class':'t11'}).get_text()
        article = soup.find_all('div',{'id':'articleBodyContents'})

        chrome_driver.quit()
        
        self.set_title(title)
        self.set_date(date)
```

Comment: What is your target?

Comment: What's the real text instead of `target data`?

Comment: i couldn't upload that.i think because it's too complex. so my detail question is how can i get data at ### targetdata. exactly how can i get  data in <div class xxx id yyy> only text?

Comment: @YangDongJae Are in _target data_ any tags or is it plain text?

Comment: The html that you have provided is incomplete. It only contains the opening tags. Where are the close tags?

Comment: i edit my source code to add close tags with structure

Comment: @YangDongJae Are you able to share the URL?

Comment: @MendelG i upload target url with my source code!

Comment: @YangDongJae See my new answer.

Comment: @MendelG would you check my update question?

Comment: @YangDongJae You have another question?  I suggest you make a new post

Answer (score 1):

I think remove all sub tags will work. have a look:

```
data = """<div class='xxx' id = 'yyy'>
     <div class id = 'zzz' class='kkk'>
<script type = 'bbb'>
// noise word
</script>
<strong class = '111'>...</strong>
<span class = '222'>...</span>

<br>
### target data
<br>
### target data2
<br>
### target data 3

<a href="http://news.khan.co.kr/kh_cartoon/?utm_source=naver&amp;utm_medium=news_bottom_outlink" target="_blank">▶ 장도리 | 그림마당 보기</a><br/><a href="http://www.khan.co.kr/?utm_source=naver&amp;utm_medium=news_bottom_outlink" target="_blank">▶ 경향신문 바로가기</a><a href="http://smile.khan.co.kr/gudoc/gudoc_input_step3.html?media_cd=201&amp;utm_source=naver&amp;utm_medium=news_bottom_outlink" target="_blank">▶ 경향신문 구독신청하기</a><br/><br/>©경향신문(www.khan.co.kr), 무단전재 및 재배포 금지<br/><br/>
<!-- // 본문 내용 -->
</div>
</div>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
    for tag in soup.find('div', {'id': 'yyy'}).find_all():  # this loop delete all sub tags.
        if not tag.find_all():  # no sub tag
            tag.decompose()
    print(soup.text.strip())
```

output:

```
### target data

### target data2

### target data 3

©경향신문(www.khan.co.kr), 무단전재 및 재배포 금지
```

Comment: would you give me some advice with my update question? i wanna get the article. but when i was follow your source code,  i get all text in the page. how can i do for solve this problem?

Comment: have a look at MendelG's answer. look like it's the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to come up with clean solution, because of incomplete HTML, but this can give you an idea: you can `.extract()` non-necessary tags and leave only desired data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<div class = 'xxx' id = 'yyy'>
     <div class id = 'zzz' class = 'kkk'>
<script type = 'bbb'>
// noise word
</script>
<strong class = '111'>...</strong>
<span class = '222'>...</span>

<br>
### target data
<br>
### target data2
<br>
### target data 3

<a href="http://news.khan.co.kr/kh_cartoon/?utm_source=naver&amp;utm_medium=news_bottom_outlink" target="_blank">▶ 장도리 | 그림마당 보기</a><br/><a href="http://www.khan.co.kr/?utm_source=naver&amp;utm_medium=news_bottom_outlink" target="_blank">▶ 경향신문 바로가기</a><a href="http://smile.khan.co.kr/gudoc/gudoc_input_step3.html?media_cd=201&amp;utm_source=naver&amp;utm_medium=news_bottom_outlink" target="_blank">▶ 경향신문 구독신청하기</a><br/><br/>©경향신문(www.khan.co.kr), 무단전재 및 재배포 금지<br/><br/>
<!-- // 본문 내용 -->
</div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

div = soup.select_one('#yyy')

# remove all non-necessary tags
div.select_one('script').extract()
div.find('strong', class_='111').extract()
div.find('span', class_='222').extract()

for t in div.a.next_siblings:  # remove all tags after <a>
    t.extract()

div.a.extract()  # remove <a> itself

print(div.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div class="xxx" id="yyy">
 <div class="kkk" id="zzz">
  <br/>
  ### target data
  <br/>
  ### target data2
  <br/>
  ### target data 3
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple CSS Selectors to scrape the correct data:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://news.naver.com/main/read.nhn?mode=LS2D&mid=shm&sid1=100&sid2=264&oid=016&aid=0001737526"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

for tags1, tags2 in zip(
    soup.select(
        "#articleBodyContents > br:nth-child(5), br:nth-child(7), br:nth-child(9)"
    ),
    soup.select("#articleBodyContents > span:nth-child(10)"),
):
    print(tags1.next)
    print(tags2.next.next)
```

Output:

```
[헤럴드경제=강문규 기자] 문재인 대통령은 14일 라임·옵티머스 사건과 관련해 청와대 참... And on
```

Comment: I think it's great solution. but it's not fit to my project. because i have to implement to get all article which have different css structure. But Thanks anyway